# access a variable of another class via a property

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, oop, properties

I have two classes,In classA I create a variable that I need to use in classB , 
should i use property ?

is there anyone to explain me easier ,how to set StringValue of variable in one class to the textfield of another class?

thanks

Comment: Have you seen http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and yes:

http://www.cocoacast.com/?q=node/103

Comment: broken link? this now just offers hosting.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Feel free to search the web and un break the link if you'd like. I found it originally via web search anyway

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is Yes, use properties, that is what they are for: a simple way of exposing the state of an object to other objects.

The longer answer is that [Objective-C 2.0 properties](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProperties.html) are just a wrapper around the concept of [Key-Value-Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html) and [Key-Value-Observing](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000177-BCICJDHA) (KVC/KVO).

It is well worth reading the documentation for these as the concept is fundamental to the way that Cocoa works and understanding them early on in your learning process will save you a lot of trouble in the future.

And, since you will be passing object references around I might as well add a link to the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) which will help you correctly apply the proper memory management attributes to your `@property` declarations.

Comment: Properties are just a formal syntax for declaring accessor methods and (in the modern runtime) instance variables. KVC is a way to access such a property, whether it was formally declared or not. The distinction is that `foo.bar` directly sends a `bar` message to `foo`, exactly as `[foo bar]` would, whereas KVC will actually *look for* a method like `bar` or `_bar` and only send a message if it finds one (and it will peek the `bar` or `_bar` ivar if it doesn't find a method). So, KVC mostly sits on top of properties; properties do not wrap KVC.

Comment: I was trying to say that properties simplify creating KVC compliant accessors, even down to `@synthesize _iVar = iVar;`

Comment: is there anyone to explain me easier how to set StringValue of variable of one class to the textfield of another class?

Comment: Have a look at Cocoa Bindings http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Concepts/WhatAreBindings.html